# Generate Parser for a File with JavaCC

Tags: javacc

I am a beginner with JavaCC,and i'm trying to generate a file Parser.

I have already been able to generate a successful parser interpenetrated a line that is entered on the keyboard.
Parser example when I enter the keyboard "First Name: William", I managed to display on the screen the name of the variable and the value.

Now I have a file .txt who contain a large number of names and their value, and I would like to successfully display them on the screen.

below is my .jj file that I have already written to generate a parser of a typed line

Now i want the same but for a file.

```
options
{
  static = true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(parser_name)

public class parser_name
{
  public static void main(String args []) throws ParseException
  {
    System.out.println("Waiting for the Input:");
    parser_name parser = new parser_name(System.in);
    parser.Start();
  }
}

PARSER_END(parser_name)

SKIP :
{
  " "
| "\r"
| "\t"
| "\n"
}


TOKEN : { < DIGIT : (["0"-"9"])+ > }

TOKEN : { <VARIABLE: (["a"-"z", "A"-"Z"])+> }

TOKEN : { <VALUE: (~["\n",":"])+> }

TOKEN : { <ASSIGNMENT: ":"> }


void Start(): { Token t,t1,t2;}
{
    t=<VARIABLE>
    t1=<ASSIGNMENT>
    t2=<VALUE>
    { System.out.println("The Variable is "+t.image+",and the Value is "+t2.image); }
}
```

I have already tried to replace the "System.in" at the parser constructor with an object of type File.And then read the file by line, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Reader to the parser's constructor.